# Не понятен пример из книги о Java. Как присваивать объекты полям экземпляра?

Tags: java

```
class GuessGame {
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;
    public void startGame() {
        p1 = new Player();
        p2 = new Player();
        p3 = new Player();
        int guessp1 = 0;
        int guessp2 = 0;
        int guessp3 = 0;
        boolean p1isRight = false;
        boolean p2isRight = false;
        boolean p3isRight = false;
        int targetNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("я загадываю число от 0 до 9...");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("число, которое нужно угадать, - " + targetNumber);
            p1.guess();
            p2.guess();
            p3.guess();
            guessp1 = p1.number;
            System.out.println("первый игрок думает, что это " + guessp1);
            guessp2 = p2.number;
            System.out.println("второй игрок думает, что это " + guessp2);
            guessp3 = p3.number;
            System.out.println("третий игрок думает, что это " + guessp3);
            if(guessp1 == targetNumber) {
                p1isRight = true;
            }
            if(guessp2 == targetNumber) {
                p2isRight = true;
            }
            if(guessp3 == targetNumber) {
                p3isRight = true;
            }
            if(p1isRight || p2isRight || p3isRight) {
                System.out.println("у нас есть победитель!");
                System.out.println("первый игрок угадал?" + p1isRight);
                System.out.println("второй игрок угадал?" + p2isRight);
                System.out.println("третий игрок угадал?" + p3isRight);
                System.out.println("конец игры.");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("игроки должны попробовать еще раз.");
            }
        }
    }
}
class Player {
    int number = 0;
    public void guess() {
        number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("думаю, это число " + number);
    }
}
public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
        game.startGame();
    }
}
```

в первых 4-х строчках содержатся 3 поля экземпляра для 3-х объектов Player:

```
class GuessGame {
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    Player p3;
```

создаются 3 объекта Player и присваиваются трём переменным экземпляра:

```
public void startGame() {
    

    p1 = new Player();
    p2 = new Player();
    p3 = new Player();
```

я убрал поля экземпляра, и написал так:

```
class GuessGame {
    public void startGame() {
        Player p1 = new Player();
        Player p2 = new Player();
        Player p3 = new Player();
```

и программа, по-моему работает так же.
просто я думал, что переменные экземпляра это свойства для описания объекта типа int,String и т.д., и что их нельзя присваивать объекту. а в примере можно. кто-нибудь подскажите как это работает? и какая разница между примером в книге и моим изменением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то поле класса (то, что вы называете переменной экземпляра) имеет область видимости на весь класс, а переменная метода только в пределах метода.

В вашем примере объекты p1, p2, p3 будут доступны только внутри метода startGame(), в примере из книги - в любом методе класса. Конкретно в этом коде существенной разницы в части исполнения кода не будет, так как в классе всего один метод startGame(), но если вы захотите добавить какой - нибудь метод score() для подсчёта очков игроков, то ваш вариант уже окажется не рабочим, так как получить доступ к  объектам p1 p2 p3 за пределами метода startGame() вы не сможете.

Так же, Поля класса уничтожаются только при уничтожении объекта класса, переменные методов - после того, как метод закончен. При следующем вызове этого метода такие переменные будут созданы заново и их прежние значения утрачены. В контексте вашей игры это может быть метод pause() для приостановки игры, вызвав startGame() повторно, в случае вашего кода, вы потеряете весь прогресс, в коде из книги он будет сохранен.

Для подробностей и нюансов почитайте про области видимости переменных в Java.

И да, полем класса может быть любой объект или примитив, не обязательно для хранения именно свойств, а исходя из видимости для остальных частей программы.

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: @артёмлобза Что здесь принято делать, чтобы [сказать "спасибо"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)